# How HTTPS is different than HTTP request?

Tags: http, ssl, https

I understand that HTTTPS is secured and it requires SSL certificate issued by CA authority to make the application secure. But what I do not understand is that its in-depth difference with HTTP.

My question, as a user, if I make a request to an application with HTTP or if I make same request to HTTPS what is the actual difference? The traffic remains same to both. Is there any traffic filtering happening if I use HTTPS?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS, as an application protocol is just HTTP over TLS, so there are very few differences, the `s` in the URL and some consequences for proxy, that is all.

Now you are speaking about the traffic and the filtering. Here you have a big difference because using TLS adds confidentiality and integrity: passive listeners will see nothing about the HTTP data exchanged, including headers. The only thing visible will be the hostname (taken from the `https://` URL) as this is needed at the TLS level before HTTP even happens, through a mechanism called SNI (Server Name Indication) that is now used everywhere to be able to install multiple services using TLS under different names but with a single IP address.